# jquery navigation on active change color and background color not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

i am making an website having
master >submaster >page.aspx
i want that if any user click on the link in navigation bar it changes the color of that particular link as well change the color of background ,my navigation is in submaster page ,
i have used jquery but its not working ,on page load it goes disappear .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#HomeLink').click(function () {
        $('#HomeLink').css("background-color","white");
        $('#HomeLink').css("color","#00AEEC");
    });
});

<div id="UpperMenu">
                <h2><a href="#">Horizon</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home.aspx"><div id="HomeLink"><span class="NavLink">Home</span></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div id="NewLink"><span class="NavLink">New</span></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div id="LookupLink"><span class="NavLink">Lookup</span></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="Reports.aspx"><div id="ReportLink"><span class="NavLink">Report</span></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div id="ManageLink"><span class="NavLink">Manage</span></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div id="UtilitiesLink"><span class="NavLink">Utilities</span></div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: You're appliying the styles both to the same id `homelink`. You shoud select the background `id` to apply `background-color`

Comment: jQuery works on events . these events effects vanished after page reload/refresh. background color and color effect will not be permanent when page get refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HomeLink's color is overwrited by other css attribute, could you show your html and css code here?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine in your code but you can simplify this way:

As your edit i just saw the html your `div has <span>` and `these are the children of <a>` so you can do two things:

1. change the text color of the a
2. Change the background of the span

   ```
   $('#HomeLink').click(function() {
      $(".NavLink",this).css("background-color", "red");
      $(this).closest('a').css("color", "white");
   });
   ```

and `make sure you have a reference to the jQuery plugin` at top of this script.

you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5WSuv/1/

Comment: yes i have given the link even i have check it with alert function and thats working well

Comment: the problem is that ...my script is working but i have redirect the page on another page on click event so its reload the page ...in this case its not showing the change

Comment: yes sure this happens when navigating to other pages script will go at the default and your changes will not reflect. Instead of this why don't you use `ajax` for this.

Comment: but your question was different and now your problem is different, Plz always post the correct issue to get it resolved.

Comment: i think we can do it by using inline css but we have to put the navigation on each page

Comment: there is another way just compare the page heading tags and apply the css via jquery, this would be easy and small.

Answer (score 0):

rather than having two references to #homelink try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#HomeLink').click(function () {
    $('#HomeLink').css({
                    background-color : '#FFF',
                    color : '#00AEEC'
     });  
});
```

You should be able run it in shot rather than running it twice.